# Puppet and Apache: ${name} gives 'main' instead of class name

Tags: apache, puppet, puppetlabs-apache

I'm trying to configure a few Apache virtual hosts with the `puppetlabs/apache` module. My issue is with the `${name}` variable. I expected DocumentRoot to be set to `/var/www/atoms.one`, but instead it is set to `/var/www/main`.

What am I doing wrong?

My manifest:

```
class { apache: }

apache::vhost { 'atoms.one':
    port          => '80',
    serveraliases => [ "*.${name}" ],
    docroot       => "/var/www/${name}",
    directories   => [
        { path => "/var/www/${name}", },
    ],
}
```

Answer (score 1):

*Inside a defined type's body*, the special variable `$name` represents the name / title of the defined type instance.  But you have not presented a defined-type body -- rather, you have presented a declaration of a defined-type instance, and one that appears at top scope, at that.  The declaration does not create a scope for `$name` to mean anything different within than it does without.

I'm having trouble finding documentation for the meaning of `$name` outside the scope of a defined-type body, but I know from experience that inside a class it represents the class name.  I suppose you are seeing the name of the top scope, for which "main" is a plausible value.

The bottom line is that `$name` does not provide the kind of shortcut you are trying to use it for.  You could instead create a defined type wrapper of your own around `apache::vhost`, and do the shortcutting there.  Alternatively, you could create your own variable to use instead of `$name`.